# Solving a trigonometric system of equations related to addition formulas.

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have the following trigonometric system of equations.

$
\begin{align*}
&& \sin(x)\cos(y) &= \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{4} \\ 
&& \cos(x)\sin(y) &= \frac{-1+\sqrt{3}}{4} \\
\end{align*}
$

I am trying to find a quick way to solve this system for $x$ and $y$ with $0<x,y<\frac{\pi}{2}$. I have managed to find one set of solutions ($x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $y=\frac{\pi}{12}$) but I am unable to find the other pair which I can clearly see after graphing the system.

[image]

I was able to deduce, by making use of the addition formula for $sin$, that:
$\begin{align*}
&&\sin(x + y) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \implies x + y = \frac{\pi}{3}
\end{align*}$
Using this fact, I found my pair of solutions by forming a quadratic in $\tan(x)$ after playing around with addition formula for $\tan$.

I am certain there is an easier way to solve the problem that I am missing. Any tips for solving this system would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you try the formula for $\sin(x-y)$?

Comment: $$\begin{align*}
&&sin(x + y) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \implies (x + y = \frac{\pi}{3} )OR  (x + y = \frac{2\pi}{3} )
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @A.Γ. Wow, I knew I missing something stupid... $sin(x - y)$ is what I was missing thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\begin{align*}
\sin(x + y) &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} &\implies x + y = \left\{\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{2\pi}{3}\right\}+2\pi n\\
\sin(x - y) &= \frac{1}{2} &\implies x - y = \left\{\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}\right\}+2\pi n\\
\end{align*}
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the $sin(x - y)$...

Comment: @Max If you use only this fact you will find only one solution in the interval $[0,2\pi)$. To find all solutions you need also the fact that there are two possible values both for $x+y$ and $x-y$ in the interval.